# Set a table columns width

Tags: css, html-table

I tried to do it by adjusting the  width:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
div {width:100%; overflow:auto;}
table, td {border:1px solid #000;}
td {width:1000px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>First cell</td>
<td>Second cell</td>
<td>Third cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Forth cell</td>
<td>Fifth cell</td>
<td>Sixth cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding table headers using the <th> tag and use CSS to change the width of those instead of the <td>s

Comment: @CFL_Jeff: Just tried it to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table layout must be fixed for your columns widths to be fixed:

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
```

Comment: I already tried a fixed layout without width:100% -- this is the point I missed. Thanks for the answer! :)